# Dart: The concrete return type isn't of type generic

Tags: dart

This is something I would like to achieve in `Dart`:

```
typedef Adder<T> = T Function<T>(T a, T b);

Adder<int> createIntAdder() {
  int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  return add;
}
```

The code above does not compile.

Nor does this:

```
Adder<int> createIntAdder() {
  return (int a, int b) => a + b;
}
```

It says:

`The return type '(int, int) -> int' isn't a '<T>(T, T) -> T', as defined by the method 'createIntAdder'.`

And I never said it was. I am returning a concrete type `int` and *not*  the generic `T`.

Could anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got the typedef wrong. It should properly be:

```
typedef Adder<T> = T Function(T a, T b);
```

I am not entirely sure what kind of return type you get with your typedef but it seems wrong to have doubled the generic part.

Comment: Good catch. The second generic `<T>` was also underlined and IDE said `Avoid shadowing type parameters.`. Didn't see that when I posted.